# 'Url' for SharePoint item in SocialDataService.GetTags(url)

Tags: 2010, development, url, .net, tags

I am calling the '[SocialDataService.GetTags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvcsocialdataservice.socialdataservice.gettags.aspx)' web service method to try and obtain the Tags for a specific SharePoint item in a list or for a SharePoint document in a Document library.

For the Document I use the 'FileRef' property value to calculate the URL but the same does not work for a SharePoint item.

What is the best way to construct a URL for an item or document which can be used in the 'GetTags' method?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently [SPListItem.Url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.url.aspx) for Lists  could not be used in Social Tags since the methods:

```
SocialTagManager.GetTags Method (Uri)
```

and

```
SocialTagManager.AddTag Method (Uri, Term)
```

expect a valid URI to be provided.

But in case of Lists the url of list item **form** could be specified as demonstrated below:

```
http://intranet.contoso.com/Lists/Nokia Offices/DispForm.aspx?id=1
```

The following method could be used for determining SPListItem Url:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Generic method for retrieving SPListItem Url
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetListItemUrl(this SPListItem item)
    {
        string itemUrl = null;
        switch (item.ParentList.BaseType)
        {
            case SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary:
                itemUrl = SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(item.Web.Url, item.Url);
                break;
            case SPBaseType.DiscussionBoard:
            case SPBaseType.Issue:
            case SPBaseType.Survey:
            case SPBaseType.GenericList:
                //Display Form By default
                itemUrl = item.Web.Url + "/" + item.ParentList.Forms[PAGETYPE.PAGE_DISPLAYFORM].Url + "?id=" + item.ID;
                break;
        }
        return itemUrl;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Btw do you have any idea how about this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18506686/filter-sharepoint-documents-based-on-a-tag-filter-using-the-client-object-model

Comment: What is the value that should be used to index the 'Forms' collection? Is that something I get from the API or can I use a fixed value there?

Comment: PAGETYPE.PAGE_DISPLAYFORM (value 4) specifies the type of a display form, for all available types please follow MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.pagetype(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Since I am using the Client Object Model, I used the 'List.Forms.GetByPageType(PageType.DisplayForm)' method.